# ROR: To scaffold or not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I love scaffolding and it extremely helpful for prototyping. But Should we use scaffolding for developing application as such?

Comment: Would you mind explaining what scaffolding is?

Comment: Scaffolding is: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#getting-up-and-running-quickly-with-scaffolding

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The name "scaffolding" is sort of a misnomer in Rails now (post 2.0). The structure generated through scaffolding generator is more of a base application to build on, rather than a "prototype" that you throw away later.

At least, if you are designing your application to be RESTful, you will find yourself keeping most of the scaffold generator produced controller and model code, while adding more logic to them. You will perhaps replace the views eventually while keeping bits and pieces of Ruby code in them.

Answer (score 3):

There is no harm in using scaffold to kick-start development of your application. However, if you are a newbie you need to understand how stuff can be done without it.  Scaffold is a tool for rapid prototype development in rails and can be used if you can alter it to suit your requirements quickly.

Answer (score 2):

i use it a lot

i strt off with scaffolding and then gradually replace it with custom code; it's a great way to get something up and running pretty quick.

Answer (score 0):

Actually It's depends on your requirements. When we consider about the scaffold it will generate CRUD(Create, Read, Update and Delete) operations instantly. So if you need to remove some of operations its really easy if you coded it manually. But that also can be done by using scaffold also. Just you have to remove those methods only.
So it's your choice whether you use it or not

Answer (score 0):

I have read some books,the author all told me that a for developer will not use it in they business project.So I am not using it in my project any time.But it is only my options,it is up to you.